# Python concatenate list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm new to python and this is just to automate something on my PC. I want to concatenate all the items in a list. The problem is that

```
''.join(list)
```

won't work as it isn't a list of strings.

This site http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/ says the most efficient way to do it is

```
''.join([`num` for num in xrange(loop_count)])
```

but that isn't valid python...

Can someone explain the correct syntax for including this sort of loop in a string.join()?

Comment: It seems the backtick syntax was [removed in python 3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax).

Answer (score 19):

You need to turn everything in the list into strings, using the [`str()` constructor](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str):

```
''.join(str(elem) for elem in lst)
```

Note that it's generally not a good idea to use `list` for a variable name, it'll shadow the built-in `list` constructor.

I've used a generator expression there to apply the `str()` constructor on each and every element in the list. An alternative method is to use the [`map()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```
''.join(map(str, lst))
```

The backticks in your example are another spelling of calling [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) on a value, which is subtly different from `str()`; you probably want the latter. Because it violates the Python principle of ["There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), the backticks syntax has been removed from Python 3.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. All these differences between v2 and v3 are really annoying, and I can't yet tell which version a googled piece of code will work in!

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way (discussion is about Python 2.x):

```
''.join(map(str, my_list))
```

This solution will have the fastest performance and it looks nice and simple imo. Using a generator won't be more efficient. In fact this will be more efficient, as `''.join` has to allocate the exact amount of memory for the string based on the length of the elements so it will need to consume the whole generator before creating the string anyway.

Note that ``` `` ``` has been removed in Python 3 and it's not good practice to use it anymore, be more explicit by using `str()` if you have to eg. `str(num)`.

Comment: @gnibbler noted that at the top

Answer (score 2):

just use this, no need of `[]` and use `str(num)`:

```
''.join(str(num) for num in xrange(loop_count))
```

for list just replace `xrange(loop_count)` with the list name.

example:

```
   >>> ''.join(str(num) for num in xrange(10)) #use range() in python 3.x
    '0123456789'
```

Comment: Not really what the OP was asking for; the `for num in xrange(loop_count)` example is a distraction, really.

Answer (score 2):

If your Python is too old for "list comprehensions" (the odd `[x for x in ...]` syntax), use `map()`:

```
 ''.join(map(str, list))
```

Comment: The fact that the OP got a syntax error is an indication we are talking about Python 3.x here; it'll be new enough for a generator expression. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I read that as the exact opposite: He has a syntax error and doesn't know how to fix it.

Comment: The code is legal in Python 2; I was addressing your `python is too old for list comprehensions remark. :-)

Comment: He might be using Python 1.6.

Comment: *Highly* unlikely, that hasn't been current for over a decade!

Comment: yup, hit the nail on the head Martijn.